# Skip Drive during Powershell Iteration

Tags: powershell

I'm currently listing all the lists of drives in my computer. However, I want to skip the C:\ drive from the output:

This is my code:

```
# Iterates over all drives found
$SortedDrives = $Drives | Sort-Object -Property Used -Descending

foreach ($Drive in $SortedDrives) {
    if ($Drive.Name -eq "C") {
        continue
    }

    Write-Output $Drive.Root
    $newSortedDrives = $newSortedDrives += $Drive.Root
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                      ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                           ---------------
C                 150.62        688.78 FileSystem    C:\                                                                                           
I                   2.42         65.94 FileSystem    I:\                                                                                           
F                   0.09          2.96 FileSystem    F:\                                                                                           
G                   0.05         16.43 FileSystem    G:\                                                                                           
D                   0.05         15.67 FileSystem    D:\                                                                                           
H                   0.03          9.73 FileSystem    H:\
```

Ideally, I want the C drive to be skipped and only display drives I F G D H.

What am I doing wrong? It looks like this instruction:

```
if ($Drive.Name -eq "C") {
    continue
}
```

Is not doing what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Aside from missing initialization `$newSortedDrives = @()` before the loop), **the code in your question now works correctly and as expected**, because you later edited your question to fix the original problem, which was using the *wrong variable* as the enumeration source in the `foreach` loop.

A more concise, PowerShell-idiomatic formulation of your code is (PSv3+):

```sh
# Collects just the .Root property values; omit the (...).Root to get drive objects.
[array] $newSortedDrives = (Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | 
                              Where-Object Name -ne C | 
                                Sort-Object -Property Used -Descending).Root
```

This avoids the inefficient iterative construction of your output array `$newSortedDrives`, because using `+=` to "append" to an array actually creates a *new* array with the new element appended behind the scenes.

Note how `(...).Root` is used to provide the *array* of `.Root` property values automatically collected by accessing that property on the individual *elements* of the input collection, a feature called [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375).

It also shows that ***filtering* a *collection* is a natural fit for PowerShell's pipeline via the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet**.

In the realm of *expressions* (things already collected in memory) there is also **the faster PSv4+ `.Where()` [array (collection) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#where)**; e.g.:

```sh
PS> ('C', 'A', 'B').Where({ $_ -ne 'C' })
A
B
```